# NGX translate in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-translate

Oops guys, how are you?
I'm having a problem using ngx translate on this project with Angular 9, it's not getting the translations that are in Assets.
Can you help me with this?
Apparently everything is fine.

```js
appModule 
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
  })






Assets/i18n/
{
  "english": "Angular 9 Example",
  "portuguese": "Welcome to our app!"
}
```

```css
Home Component  /

imports : [
TranslateModule
]

Home Component

constructor (private translate: TranslateService) { }

ngonit() {
translate.setDefaultLang('en');
}
```

```html
<h2>{{ 'english' | translate }}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `path` of your `i18n` translation file should be included within the `HttpLoaderFactory` to be loaded correctly before using it.

```js
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Then, the selected language should be defined using `translate.use('en')`:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  this.translate.use('en');
}
```

In case you're using an `interceptor` (e.g. `AuthInterceptor`), you should force it to handle the requests start with `baseUrl` only, and ignore the local ones, like the following:

```js
intercept(
  request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
  next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if (request.url.startsWith(environment.baseUrl)) {
    // Add your logic here
    // e.g. inject the token and next.handle the request again
  } else {
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it this way but it's giving the following error

img: https://ibb.co/y6StBLt

Comment: As I understand it, instead of trying to get it from the assets folder it is doing a get in the Back End, but I don't understand why yet

Comment: Could you please include your `angular.json` content file, and mention if you're using any interceptor in your Angular app?

Comment: I added angular.json in another post, can you see?

Comment: I updated my answer in case you're using any interceptors as I mentioned here before.

Comment: Perfect bro, it helped me a lot.
I did this if in auth and it worked "
if(req.url == "./assets/i18n/en.json") {return next.handle(req); }".
Thank you very much